# A result of Stieltjes Integral

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

While studying the Riemann - Stieltjes integral, I read this exercise in my book:

"Let $f:[a, b]\to \mathbb{R}$ be a bounded function. Denoted $L(P, f)$ the lower Darboux sum and $|P|$ the mesh of the partition $P$. Prove that for every $\epsilon>0$, there exists $\delta>0$ such that for every partition $P$ with $|P|<\delta$, we have: $\underline{\int_{a}^{b}}f(x)dx-L(P, f)<\epsilon$."

My question is: Can we generalize this problem for Stieltjes integral, with $\underline{\int_{a}^{b}}f(x)d\alpha$ instead of $\underline{\int_{a}^{b}}f(x)dx$?

Particularly, can we have this theorem?

Let $f:[a, b]\to \mathbb{R}$ be a bounded function and $\alpha$ is a monotonic function on $[a, b]$ . Denoted $L(P, f, \alpha)$ the lower Darboux sum and $|P|$ the mesh of the partition $P$. Prove that for every $\epsilon>0$, there exists $\delta>0$ such that $\underline{\int_{a}^{b}}f(x)d\alpha-L(P, f, \alpha)<\epsilon$ for every partition $P$ with $|P|<\delta$?

I don't know how the mesh of the partition relate to the function $\alpha$.

Answer (score 0):

Exactly,
That is one of the Riemann - Stieltjes integral properties. The proof is related to the properties of supremum.
The mesh of the partition is not relate to the function $\alpha.$

Comment: If the mesh is not relate to the function $\alpha$, so how we use $|P|<\delta$?. I've tried to use the same idea when I solved the case of Riemann integral, but it doesn't seem to work. Could you give me a hint?

Comment: The lower Riemann - Stieltjes integral $\underline{\int_{a}^{b}} f(x)d\alpha$ is defined as the supremum of $L(P, f, \alpha)$, so there exists a partition $P$ such that $\underline{\int_{a}^{b}} f(x)d\alpha - L(P, f, \alpha)< \epsilon$. For any partition $P^{*}$, I put $L(P^{*}, f, \alpha)$ into two sums $S_{1}, S_{2}$. $S_{1}$ consists of all subintervals of $P^{*}$ which don't contain any point of $P$ and $S_{2}$ contains the other subintervals. This is my idea, but now I'm stuck.

Comment: it is only related to $f$  in both Riemann and Riemann Stieltjes case.

Comment: Do you mean when the mesh is small, the infimum of $f$ will increase?Can you show me the idea?